# MySQL transform 3 queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 working simple queries. How could I transform in one query?

```
// query 1
SELECT PropertyName From Properties Where PropertyID = 1

// query 2
Select Count(*) as totalTenants From Tenants Where Prospect = 2 and PropertyID = 1

// query 3
Select Count(*) as totalUnits From units Where PropertyID = 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Show the results that you want.

Comment: Without sample data, your question is not really answerable.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's hardly true in this case.

Comment: @Barmar That also depends on your translation of the word `hardly`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Why downvote my post? No need for sample data. If you don't know the answer, it's fine. Try to learn it with me.

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 I did **not** downvote your post, it was someone else.  I did, however, vote as unclear what you are asking.  I stand by that voting decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want:

```
select p.PropertyName,
       (select count(*) as totalTenants 
        from Tenants t
        where t.Prospect = 2 and t.PropertyID = p.PropertyID
       ),
       (select count(*) as totalTenants 
        from Units u
        where u.PropertyID = p.PropertyID
       )
from Properties p
where p.PropertyID = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for. You just forgot to add 'p' ```after from Properties```